# GPS Mission Planning in ROS?

Tags: gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on my entry for Sparkfun's [Autonomous Vehicle Competition](https://avc.sparkfun.com/), and my current mission planning software is non-existent.

Can anyone recommend a good mission-planning software that would allow me to create a series of GPS waypoints on a map? Bonus points if it integrates well with ROS and rviz, and can be used offline.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210901/gps-mission-planning-in-ros?/) by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47576 on 2015-06-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For reference, I ended up writing a simple tool which converts KML/KMZ files into my custom path format: https://github.com/trainman419/dagny_robomagellan/blob/670a45856950bc4008bbe05aa838a7b1c70a9332/goal_list/scripts/kml2yaml.py

This means that I can do my mission planning in Google Maps, Google Earth or any other KML editor, and then quickly convert that result for use on my robot.

**EDIT**

I also considered [rviz_satellite](https://github.com/gareth-cross/rviz_satellite) and the Qt Marble framework, but the lack of easily-usable, high-res satellite maps means that they're not very useful for planning a mission the size of AVC.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1